# Checking if a date exists or not in Java

Tags: java, date

Is there any predefined class in Java such that, if I pass it a date it should return if it is a valid date or not? For example if I pass it 31st of February of some year, then it should return false, and if the date exists then it should return me true, for any date of any year.

And I also want a method that would tell me what weekday this particular date is. I went through the Calender class but I didn't get how to do this.

Comment: If you try to create a date object that doesn't exist it will probably throw an exception. Not sure though, never used dates in java.

Comment: @st0le - what?  Are you unsure too?  :-)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

[How to Validate a Date in Java](http://www.ehow.com/how_6308097_validate-date-java.html)

```java
private static boolean isValidDate(String input) {
    String formatString = "MM/dd/yyyy";
    
    try {
        SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat(formatString);
        format.setLenient(false);
        format.parse(input);
    } catch (ParseException | IllegalArgumentException e) {
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}

public static void main(String[] args){
    System.out.println(isValidDate("45/23/234")); // false
    System.out.println(isValidDate("12/12/2111")); // true
}
```

Comment: you are welcome. have a look at SimpleDateFormat http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html. you can modify formatString to your needs for a week day, for an hour even for a minute :)

Comment: @sasidhar I really recommend you have a look at joda time.  It will be the standard date API starting from JDK7 but you can use it now.  It has all kinds of nice methods, one being getDatOfWeek.

Comment: Its returning that 31st of February exists............ it is simply checking if the date is less than 31 and month is less than 12 and year is valid.... thats all.... but thats not the functionality i want.... :( please help....

Answer (score 7):

The key is to call [DateFormat#isLenient(`false`)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html#isLenient%28%29) so it won't roll values that are out of range during parsing:

```
DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
format.parse("2010-02-31"); //=> Ok, rolls to "Wed Mar 03 00:00:00 PST 2010".
format.setLenient(false);
format.parse("2010-02-31"); //=> Throws ParseException "Unparseable date".
```

Of course, you can use any actual date format you require.

Answer (score -2):

You can use this to get weekday from the date

> ```
>     Calendar currentDate = Calendar.getInstance(); //or your specified date.
>     int weekDay = currentDate.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
> ```